# How to make a Ribbon in GUI Java (like Office 2013 Ribbon)?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, toolbar

I'm working on an interface for a desktop application in Java
and I'm using GUI in NetBeans.

So, I want to add a ribbon like the one in Microsoft Office 2013 to my app
but it's not included in GUI tools!

**Does** anyone have an idea to add a ribbon to my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using **Flamingo ribbon component**  :

- Library download link:

  https://java.net/projects/flamingo
- How to use the ribbon component:

  https://blog.frankel.ch/flamingo-tutorial/

  http://www.slideshare.net/kirillcool/flamingo-ribbon-component

Comment: It was reanimated in December 2016, there were Maintenance Updates since February 2017 and [now Flamingo is part of Project Radiance](https://www.pushing-pixels.org/2018/05/23/hello-radiance.html).